# How to wait for a folder/file to be complete to finally process it in Python?

Tags: python, process, permissions

I'm trying to code a little script that watches a defined directory with a while-loop. Every file or directory that is in this directory is compressed to RAR and moved to another directory after the process is completed.
My problem: everytime I copy a file or folder to this directory, the script doesn't wait and startes the process the second it sees a new file or folder. But when the files or folders are bigger than a few kilobytes the loop breaks with a permission error.
Since I'm a Python beginner I don't know which module to use. Is there a checking module to see if the file or folder that the tool wants to process is used by another process? Or am I going in the wrong direction?
Edit: added the code **for directory-only listening**:

```
watchDir = "L:\\PythonTest\\testfolder\\"
finishedDir = "L:\\PythonTest\\finishedfolders\\"
rarfilesDir = "L:\\PythonTest\\rarfiles\\"
rarExe = "L:\\PythonTest\\rar.exe"
rarExtension = ".rar"
rarCommand = "a"

while True:
    dirList = [name for name in os.listdir(watchDir) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(watchDir,name))]
    for entryName in dirList:
        if not os.path.exists((os.path.join(finishedDir,entryName))):
            sourcePath = os.path.join(watchDir,entryName)
            entryNameStripped = entryName.replace(" ", "")
            os.chdir(watchDir)
            archiveName = rarfilesDir+entryNameStripped+rarExtension
            subprocesscall = [rarExe, rarCommand, archiveName, entryName]
            subprocess.call(subprocesscall, shell=True)
            shutil.move(sourcePath,finishedDir)
```

When I run the script and try to add a file of several GB (named #filename# in the following lines) these errors occur:

```
Creating archive L:\PythonTest\rarfiles\#filename#.rar

Cannot open #filename#
The process cannot access the file, since it's used by another process.
Adding    #filename#                      OK 
WARNING: Cannot open 1 file
Done

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 522, in move
os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access denied: #filepath#

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "L:/Python Test/test.py", line 35, in <module>
shutil.move(sourcePath,finishedDir)
File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 531, in move
copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 342, in copytree
raise Error(errors)
shutil.Error: #filepath#
```

Comment: Please show some code that would raise this error.

Comment: Also, http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I added the code and the error text also.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using os.listdir, you can use os.walk, os.walk yields 3 tuple dirpath(path of directory,filenames(all files in that dirpath),dirnames(all the sub directories in dirpath)

```
for x,y,z in os.walk('path-of-directory'):
    do you stuff with x,y,z the three tuples
```

Comment: Thx, will keep that in mind but that doesn't solve the initial problem. :)